# Docker is not running, but it is already running

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, ide, containers

[image]

I have my Docker Desktop Running and I have run `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon` command on my cmd. But when I add `Remote-Containers: Reopen in Container` on my VS Code Command Palette, I got error like the picture above, and I'm using Windows. I don't know what should I do. Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart service docker manually.

Sometimes daemon docker on windows doesn't work and you have to restart service docker